# Xcode 12, How to suppress "Double-quoted include in framework header" warnings throughout entire project

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, ios14, xcode12

With Xcode 12 there is a new default warning which will throw a warning anywhere you #import or #include with `"quotes.h"` instead of `<brackets.h>`.

> Warning: "Double-quoted include in framework header"

How do you turn off this warning for the entire project?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think a simpler way is to go in the project's Build Settings a just set the option "Quoted Include In Framework Header" `CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER` to **No** :

[image]

Comment: Even better! Thanks

Comment: Yes agree, this wa my solution! :) Even if inside pods every time you perform `pod install`, the `project update` suggests the update.

Comment: I am a long-time linux/java/javascript developer who does most everything command-line. Since developing cross-platform I am finding the Apple way of doing things very frustrating and use fastlane for all my deploying. Can someone please explain to me how to do this without the XCode GUI? I have a build.xcconfig file but have no idea how to set this in there. Also, I did try opening my project in XCode but I don't see this setting anyway. Cheers.

Comment: UPDATE: I did find the setting but it was under All - Combined (not Basic - Combined) as the above screenshot shows. It is set to "No" yet I am getting this warning with every Pod in my project and it swamps my output so I can't find the actual problem I'm having. Sigh.

Comment: @crowmagnumb Maybe try my original solution to see if it works on your pods too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63947318/2057171

Comment: Our project uses Xcode Configuration Settings (`.xcconfig`) and Apple Docs say *Warns when a quoted include is used instead of a framework style include in a framework header.* `CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER = NO`

Answer (score 7):

You can disable these warnings for your entire project by navigating to your project's "build settings", finding the field "other linker flags" and adding the following flag:

`-Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header`

Comment: Note: When the warning is thrown if you right click on the warning and select 'Reveal in log' you will be presented with the warning in `-Waaa-bbb-ccc` format, with any warning you can change this to `-Wno-aaa-bbb-ccc` and add as a linker flag to suppress project wide.

Comment: Not working for me on Xcode 12 (latest build). -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -Wquoted-include-in-framework-header

Comment: @arcangel06 you must only use the one starting with `-Wno-` ; sometimes with linker flags I have to quit xCode and relaunch for them to take effect but most of the time it works the very next build.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work for FaceBook SDK includes

Comment: @JeffB6688 Make sure you clean project, quit and relaunch xcode and wait a minute for files to all be re-scanned by optimizer. Facebook SDK is likely very large and takes a bit for refresh to occur in background task

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Yeah, I tried that. I just can't get rid of these warnings.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like this [issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9902) is fixed as part of Cocoapods `1.10.1` (*not officially released, as of this writing*). However, you can use Cocoapods version `1.10.0.rc.1` temporarily until 1.10.1 is officially available.

```
gem install cocoapods -v '1.10.0.rc.1'
```

Another option is to update your Podfile (add below code) to disable the warning flag `CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER` setting for all pods in your project.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER'] = 'NO'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I did that, pod deintegrate and pod install

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work for FaceBook SDK includes

Comment: My cocoapods version was 1.11.3, and I still had to update the build settings for all of my pods. (But instead of updating my Podfile, I selected all of the pods in XCode and changed their build settings all at once through the UI.) I also had to `pod deintegrate` and `pod install` like @Almeida.

Answer (score 3):

I was adding the Objective C files to XCFramework.
This code

```
 #import "BlaBla.h"
```

was causing the issue:
"double-quoted include "BlaBla.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead".

I was trying to change it to #import <BlaBla.h> - but as well no success.

It seems I've figured out that I need to append the module name as well:

```
#import <ModuleName/BlaBla.h>
```

And this allowed me to build the XCFramework.

Comment: Confirm, helped to fix a new warning in Xcode 15 when it complains about the library's source header file, for example for `AFNetworking.h`: `Double-quoted include "AFURLConnectionOperation.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead"`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in Xcode 14, and solution above does not helps me. helps this steps:

1. Comment all pods in Podfile and run `pod install`
2. Remove Pods directory
3. `pod install`
4. Uncomment all pods and run `pod install`

Comment: Worked for me. I don't know how to explain it.

Comment: @OfirMalachi please rate my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the suggestion by @Silas to set this property in XCode: CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER = NO

I also had to manually set to NO by do the search and replace below.  Not sure why XCode didn't do this for me when I changed it in the XCode IDE.

CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER = YES -> NO