# GoogleDataTransport is throwing Double-quoted include in framework header expected angle-bracketed error on iOS14

Tags: swift, cocoapods, ios14

I've just update XCode to Version 12 and I'm using Firebase. I've updated pods as well but when I build the project it's giving me error:

```
Double-quoted include "pb.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead
```

These errors are multiple and in the pod of `GoogleDataTransport`

[image]

Even if I replace `""` with `<>` it still doesn't go away.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5987 Check the CocoaPods update (might not be officially released yet)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 12, How to suppress "Double-quoted include in framework header" warnings throughout entire project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63947317/xcode-12-how-to-suppress-double-quoted-include-in-framework-header-warnings-t)

Comment: @pawello2222 this doesn't solve it as these are not warnings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 12 using Firebase pods. Lexical or Preprocessor issue. "pb.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63646607/xcode-12-using-firebase-pods-lexical-or-preprocessor-issue-pb-h-file-not-fou)

Comment: I'm very surprised every single answer for this is to disable the warning. Surely Apple enabled this warning for a reason and we need to fix the root cause?

Comment: @Darren hahaha I can't agree with you more. I think the fix is on cocoapods side. According to MANY, the fix is already out in one of the latest cocoapods versions. It's not been working for me though.

Comment: Please note this also occurs when you are not using Cocoapods at all, but rather drag&drop frameworks into your project. So I am guessing the problem does not lie within Cocoapods.

Answer (score 75):

```
Apparently installing cocoapods version 1.10.0 fixes it all. 
If that doesn't work for you, please continue reading. 
There's lots of temp fixes that'll definitely work for you. 
Here's the command to uninstall and reinstall that 1.10.1 version:
```

`gem uninstall cocoapods; gem install cocoapods -v '1.10.1'`

> > > > > > ONLY CONTINUE READING IF THE ABOVE DIDN'T WORK FOR YOU.

**If you are an experienced Xcode user, just look at the image below, you'll know exactly what to do, else feel free to follow the detailed steps.**

If updating `cocoapods` didn't work for you, try this...which worked for me.

> **Please note**: *This is a workaround. Once `cocoapods` fix this in future releases, please update cocoapods instead of doing the workaround.*
>
> [@iHS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/600076/ihs) has a great [temp cocoapods fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64324297/9669133)
>
> [@haley-huynh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13970473/haley-huynh) has a great [cocoapods update example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63997424/9669133).
>
> [@bogdan-razvan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3353189/bogdan-razvan) Said that running `sudo gem install cocoapods` fixed the problem for him ... Maybe give it a shot if not already!
>
> All of those are worth giving a shot before this workaround.

With that said, we don't always have time to wait for fix releases ...So open Xcode and let's get to the workaround.

**Step 1:** `Navigate`

- In your navigator (Project files on the left), click on `Pods`
  (It usually has this blue xcode file next to it). Once you clicked on it, it should have opened the pods targets and settings on the right.

**Step 2:** `Build Settings`

- Select `Build Settings` and then also make sure `All` is selected out of the three build settings filter types (`Basic`, `Customized` and `All`)

**Step 3:** `Search`

- In the build settings, search for `quoted include`.
- You should now see the setting `Quoted Include In Framework Header`

**Step 4:** `Set to No`

- Change the value of the setting `Quoted Include In Framework Header` to `No`

**Step 4:** `Rebuild`

- **Rebuild that sexy project of yours!**

**Step 5:** `Don't be fooled`

- After rebuilding your project. If you still see errors, make sure to checkout what those errors are because it surely isn't the quote errors.

He's a picture for some visual stimulation:
[image: visual representation of the steps to fix]

Comment: it is already set to no, no effectively translates into 'dont support the double quoted include' am i wrong?

Comment: Thank you so much! Wish I found this earlier!

Comment: @Yadu are you saying selecting No didn't work for you ?

Comment: Nah man, the problem went away when I fixed the cross platform code, I mean in flutter sdk, xcode is new for me

Comment: Thanks homie, you saved me from a lot of headache and lack of sleep :)

Comment: Always a pleasure homez!

Comment: @Yadu Maybe you accidently searched in the Runner target of the Pods target? You find this in the very left column of your Xcode UI.

Comment: Running `sudo gem install cocoapods` fixed the problem for me!

Comment: @PhillipJacobs Thanks! Solved my issue too. Any idea how to make set it persistently to No? Every time I update pods this setting falls back to Yes and fails.

Comment: @ElDude Glad I could help. Interesting situation you're in. I have the same problem but only when I delete all my `PODS` folder and my `.xcworkspace`. When I do a simple pod update it keeps that setting to NO. I can't remember explicitly setting anything to persist the setting but I'll take some time to see what might cause mine not to switch back and let you know soonest!

Comment: I have a Ionic app where pods update is run at every build :) . It's annoying but I can manage.

Comment: @ElDude I complete forgot about iHS's answer below. This might just be the solution you're looking for. So just open your podfile and right at the bottom below eveything, add this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64324297/9669133

Comment: @PhillipJacobs Thanks for the link, it worked. I just saw it yesterday but I scripted the YES -> NO switch and have little less manual labor :D

Answer (score 19):

Looks like this [issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9902) is fixed as part of Cocoapods `1.10.1` (*not officially released, as of this writing*). However, you can use Cocoapods version `1.10.0.rc.1` temporarily until 1.10.1 is officially available.

```
gem install cocoapods -v '1.10.0.rc.1'
```

### Alternative solution

Another option is to update your Podfile (add below code) to disable the warning flag `CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER` setting for all pods in your project.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER'] = 'NO'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, to disable the warning flag did it.

Comment: [1.10.0](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.10.0) has since been released and does this for you.

Answer (score 9):

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/
pod deintegrate
pod update
```

Comment: Please add that you need to make sure the cocoa pods are up to date first then this will work

Answer (score 4):

I solved by updating CocoaPods to the latest stable version, which is 1.9.3, running `sudo gem install cocoapods`.

After that i updated all my pods with `pod update` and updated the swift version in Podfile to the last available

> config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '5.3'

I checked that the Clang warnings where turned off in Pod's project tab  AND GoogleDataTranport's target tag [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPZ1p.png). As mentioned in https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5987.

Finally I cleared the build folder with `CMD+Shift+K` and re-run the project with `CMD+R`

Comment: After I updated CocoaPods and pods, I got no error message; but if I click to "update to recommended settings", then the error comes back again. I just don't update for now, but this is not normal. :(

Comment: nah man I'm using the latest version but i still have the errors

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5987

The error comes from a new recommended Xcode 12 build setting. We'll investigate an update to nanopb.

In the meantime a workaround is disabling the option in the generate Pods project Build Settings:

Answer (score 0):

It's a new warning setting in Xcode 12. The issue is gone after updating the pods. And it works until you apply the recommended settings which includes a new warning. After enabling the recommended warnings, the following setting is added to the project file (project.pbxproj), which breaks the compatibility with GoogleDataTransport:

`CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER = YES;`

So, for now, just update your pods and don't update the pods project to the recommended settings. Alternatively, you could update to recommended settings and manually reset the flag afterwards to `NO`.

Comment: Dear @cybergen I already update the pods project to the recommended settings... Can you explain how to manually reset the flag to NO ?
from where and how to do this??

Comment: @Let.Simoo I didn't check this, but you should be able to find it in the projects build settings. Maybe search for the term "quoted" or "include".

Comment: Oh, there it is, in the top answer. Look at the screenshot here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63979662/590947

Answer (score 0):

The solutions about setting the CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER didn't work for my XCode version that is 12.1.  Then I checked my cococapods that was 1.9.3, updated to 1.10.1. After that it all started working.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this,

Goto Pods > build settings > search for "quoted include" > under "Quoted include in framework header" choose "No"

Xcode version 12.4

Cocoapod version 1.8.4

[Exact place of this entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFaF2.png)