# Xcode "Quoted include in Framework Header"

Tags: xcode, warnings, quote

I am using Xcode Version 12.0.1 (12A7300). When I tried to build a simple online course project, it built successfully, but I keep getting the warning to update to recommended settings regarding Quoted include in Framework Header.

I am NOT doing anything with pods at the moment. In fact, I uninstalled and removed pods completely from my Mac just in case it contributed to the problem. How do I resolve this issue?

I hesitate to click "Perform Changes" as I think this is exactly what will cause pods to blow up double-quotes vs. angle brackets issue later. I want to solve this issue first before I proceed.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I had to do this for one of my projects just now:

1. Go ahead and click "Perform Changes". This will enable the dreaded warning but also update `LastUpgradeCheck` in your Xcode project file. The new value in `LastUpgradeCheck` will prevent Xcode from showing the "Update to recommended settings" alert for this recommendation.
2. Then, manually disable the "Quoted Include In Framework Header" warning in your project file. You can follow the instructions [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63979662) if you just select "Flash Chat iOS13 project" instead of "Pods" in **Step 1**.

The result should be that your project file will have an updated line looking similar to `LastUpgradeCheck = 1210;` (possibly with a different number), and then one or more added lines with `CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER = NO;`.

If you add back in cocoapods later, you may have to repeat the steps for the Pods project, or you may be able to get by with just updating cocoapods if the fixed version is released.